# KeyError: 'st.session_state has no key in Streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

`

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu
import json
from streamlit_lottie import st_lottie
import pickle
import requests
from db1 import insert_review, fetch_all_reviews, get_movie_review

movies = pickle.load(open('movie_list.pkl', 'rb'))
similarity = pickle.load(open('similarity.pkl', 'rb'))
```

`

`

```
if selected == "Review":
    st.title("Reviews")
    with st.form("my_form"):
        st.write("Type your Review")
        user_name_rev = st.text_input("User Name")
        movie_list = movies['title'].values
        selected_movie = st.selectbox(
            "Type or select a movie from the dropdown",
            movie_list
        )
        slider_val = st.slider("Rating", 1, 10)
        # st.write(f"{slider_val}")
        movie_rev = st.text_area("Write your review")

        #checkbox_val = st.checkbox("Form checkbox")

        submitted = st.form_submit_button("Submit")

        if "load_state" not in st.session_state:
            st.session_state.load_state = False


        if submitted or st.session_state.load_state:
            st.session_state.load_state = True
            user = str(st.session_state[user_name_rev])
            movies = str(st.session_state[selected_movie])
            rate = st.session_state[slider_val]
            review = str(st.session_state[movie_rev])
            insert_review(user, movies, rate, review)
            st.write("Your review is saved")
```

I was trying to save the data in db and whenever I click submit it shows error.
`KeyError: 'st.session_state has no key "yy". Did you forget to initialize it? More info: https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state#initialization' Traceback: File "c:\users\yaagik\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 564, in _run_script exec(code, module.__dict__) File "C:\Users\YAAGIK\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\new_test.py", line 77, in <module> user = str(st.session_state[user_name_rev]) File "c:\users\yaagik\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\session_state_proxy.py", line 89, in __getitem__ return get_session_state()[key] File "c:\users\yaagik\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\safe_session_state.py", line 110, in __getitem__ return self._state[key] File "c:\users\yaagik\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\state\session_state.py", line 439, in __getitem__ raise KeyError(_missing_key_error_message(key))`

I tried to fix it with various methods available online but none of them worked for me.`

Comment: You are not posting the relevant codes. Anyway try to find the "yy" in your code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you call 'st.session_state[user_name_rev]' on line 77 without initializing it.

To initialize a streamlit session_state you can do:

```
st.session_state['your_session_state_name'] = value_to_store
```

Or

```
if 'you_session_state_name' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.you_session_state_name = value_to_store
```

In your specific case you can do:

```
if submitted or st.session_state.load_state:
    if 'user' not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state['user'] = user_name_rev
    user = str(st.session_state['user'])
```

Do the same to movies, rate, review, this might work.

References:
https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/session-state

Comment: Please check your syntax: the second period (`.`) in `st.session_state.['user']` should be removed.